# You [ had / made ] me mad

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs, causatives

What's the difference between those sentences below?

> You had me mad.

> You made me mad.

Comment: "You **had** me mad" is a very unusual choice of words.  Did you see this used somewhere?

Comment: @stangdon Google search gives me a bunch or results. Actually the one I saw was "You've got me mad", but isn't "to have got" the same as "to have"?

Comment: Most of the results I find in a Google search are actually part of a larger sentence which changes the meaning, but I see what you mean.  Yes, *you have me X* can mean *you have caused me to be X* ([example 1](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+have+me+confused%22), [example 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+had+me+confused%22&tbm=bks)) but for whatever reason we don't seem to use it much with *mad*.

Comment: @stangdon Thank you very much for this. But just one more thing. Then what's the difference between "I've caused someone to be X" and "I made someone X"? Does the former mean I did something that might or might not make(?) the person mad, but it turned out they were mad anyway, while the latter means "They got mad because I did something that surely would provoke them"?

Comment: _Have got_ can also be the present perfect of _get_, though American English prefers _have gotten_. _Getting someone angry/mad_ is not uncommon.